# Using qsort for character array in C

Tags: c, function, pointers, qsort

I'm trying to use `qsort` to sort a character array.  I can't see why this is not working.  I have a pointer to the compare function as the `man` pages specifies.  Can someone please tell me what's wrong?  Thanks.  My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int cmpfunc( const void *a, const void *b) {
  return *(int*)a - *(int*)b;
}

void AlphabetSoup( char str[] ) {
  qsort(str, (size_t) strlen(str), (size_t) sizeof(char), cmpfunc);
  printf("%s\n", str);
}


int main() {
  char str1[] = "bcead";

  AlphabetSoup(str1);

  return 0;
}
```

outputs:  `dabce` when I expect `abcde`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Simple error.

Use `char*` instead of `int*` in `cmpfunc`.

```
int cmpfunc( const void *a, const void *b) {
  return *(char*)a - *(char*)b;
}
```

When you use `int*`, instead of `char*`, the address pointed to by `a` is interpreted as an address to an `int`, not a `char`.

Your input has the following characters:

```
+---+---+---+---+---+
| b | c | e | a | d |
+---+---+---+---+---+
```

In hex, those are:

```
+----+----+----+----+----+
| 62 | 63 | 65 | 61 | 64 |
+----+----+----+----+----+
^    ^
|    |
a    b
```

If you treat the addresses pointed to `a` and `b` as `int*`, assuming an `int` takes 4 bytes in your system, `*(int*)a` can be either

```
0X62*2^24 + 0X63*2^16 + 0X65*2^8 + 0X61
```

or

```
0X62 + 0X63*2^8 + 0X65*2^16 + 0X61*2^24
```

depending on whether you have big endian system or a little endian system.

You can similarly compute what `*(int*)b` would be. As you can see, you are already running into unexpected number comparisons. By the time you start comparing the values that are at other byte locations of your input, you are also using memory that you are not supposed to use, and you are reaching the realms of undefined behavior.

Answer (score 3):

You have at least two problems here.

First, you are trying to sort the contents of a statically defined literal, which the compiler is free to store in immutable ram.

Second, and most importantly, you are casting the void* in your comparison function to an int*.  Assuming `sizeof(int) == 4`, and `sizeof(char) == 1`, you are effectively comparing characters 0-3 "as an integer" to characters 1-4 "as an integer".

In the case of `sizeof(int) = 8` (i.e., 64 bit compilers), then you would be doing even worse.  Cast the `void*` to type `char*` and you should be okay.

Comment: `str1` is initialized with `"bcead\0"` and has size 6.  It is not in "immutable ram".  Right about the `int` part.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with the type cast operator in the the compare function `comfunc`.

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
  // error. casting to int * instead of char *
  return *(int*)a - *(int*)b; 
}
```

Casting the void pointer `a` to `int *` and then dereferencing it means it will read the  `sizeof(int)` bytes from the start of the address contained in `a`. So the expression in the return statement is comparing the `sizeof(int)` number of bytes from the address in `a` with the `sizeof(int)` number of bytes from the address in `b`, instead of comparing the characters at the addresses contained in the pointers `a` and `b`. To illustrate this, I changed the compare function to

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
  printf("comparing %c and %c\n", *((char *)a), *((char *)b));
  printf("compare as int %d - %d = %d\n", *(int *)a, *(int *)b, *(int *)a - *(int *)b);
  printf("compare as char %d - %d = %d\n", *(char *)a, *(char *)b, *(char *)a - *(char *)b);
  return *(char *)a - *(char *)b;
}
```

And this is the output I get

```
comparing b and c
compare as int 1634034530 - 1684104547 = -50070017
compare as char 98 - 99 = -1
comparing a and d
compare as int 25697 - 100 = 25597
compare as char 97 - 100 = -3
comparing e and a
compare as int 6578533 - 25697 = 6552836
```

You can see the difference in the values read when comparison is done after typecasting to `int *`, and after typecasting to `char *`. The compare function should be changed to

```
int cmpfunc(const void *a, const void *b) {
      // typecast the void pointers to correct type
      return *(char *)a - *(char *)b; 
}
```

Also, you don't need to cast the result of `strlen` function and `sizeof` operator as they already return values of type `size_t`. Also, it is more readable and maintainable to use `sizeof` on the array element. You should simply call `qsort` as

```
qsort(str, strlen(str), sizeof str[0], cmpfunc);
```

Comment: Thank you for providing the solution to the problem, not just information about why (which is also helpful of course).